# Program running too slow! : Suggest Algorithmic/Implementation Optimization

Tags: python, algorithm, sqlite, optimization, python-2.7

I have a huge python list(A) of lists. The length of list A is around 90,000. Each inner list contain around 700 tuples of `(datetime.date,string)`. Now, I am analyzing this data. What I am doing is I am taking a window of size x in inner lists where- `x = len(inner list) * (some fraction <= 1)` and I am saving each ordered pair (a,b) where a occurs before b in that window (actually the innerlists are sorted wrt time). I am moving this window upto the last element adding one element at a time from one end and removing from other which takes `O(window-size)`time as I am considering the new tuples only. My code:

```
for i in xrange(window_size):
        j = i+1;
        while j<window_size:
            check_and_update(cur, my_list[i][1], my_list[j][1],log);
            j=j+1

    i=1;
    while i<=len(my_list)-window_size: 
        j=i;
        k=i+window_size-1;
        while j<k:
            check_and_update(cur, my_list[j][1], my_list[k][1],log);  
            j+=1
        i += 1
```

Here `cur` is actually a sqlite3 database cursor,`my_list` is a list containing the tuples and I iterate this code for all the lists in A and `log` is a opened logfile. In method `check_and_update()` I am looking up my database to find the tuple if exists or else I insert it, along with its total number of occurrence so far. Code:

```
def check_and_update(cur,start,end,log):    
    t = str(start)+":"+ str(end)
    cur.execute("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Extra (tuple,count)\
                 VALUES ( ? , coalesce((SELECT count +1 from Extra WHERE tuple = ?),1))",[t,t])
```

As expected this number of tuples is HUGE and I have previously experimented with dictionary which eats up the memory quite fast. So, I resorted to SQLite3, but now it is too slow. I have tried indexing but with no help. Probably the my program is spending way to much time querying and updating the database. Do you have any optimization ideas for this problem? Probably changing the algorithm or some different approach/tools. Thank you!

**Edit**: My goal here is to find the total number of tuples of strings that occur within the window grouped by the number of different innerlists they occur in. I extract this information with this query:

```
for i in range(1,size+1):       
        cur.execute('select * from Extra where count = ?',str(i))
        #other stuff
```

For Example ( I am ignoring the date entries and will write them as 'dt'):

```
My_list = [
            [ ( dt,'user1') , (dt, 'user2'), (dt, 'user3') ]
            [ ( dt,'user3') , (dt, 'user4')]
            [ ( dt,'user2') , (dt, 'user3'), (dt,'user1') ]
          ]
```

here if I take fraction = 1 then, results:

```
only 1 occurrence in window: 5 (user 1-2,1-3,3-4,2-1,3-1)
only 2 occurrence in window: 2 (user 2-3)
```

Comment: What is your actual goal? What values are you trying to compare, and why are you comparing them? What are you trying to find? It's difficult to optimize an algorithm without knowing what the end goal is.

Comment: Have you tried [NumPy](http://numpy.scipy.org/)?  It handles multidimensional arrays pretty efficiently.

Comment: You state that `my_list` is *the* 2-D list; does that mean `my_list` is A? The code seems to imply that `my_list` is one of the *inner* lists. That would mean that you only store the strings (the second component of the original tuples) in the database, is that right? On the other hand, your description doesn't mention the strings any more. I'm confused...

Comment: @WolframH: You are right, my_list actually is the inner-list. Mistake on my part, I properly edited it. The strings are the users (see the added section).

Comment: @NilanjanBasu: Ah, that clears it up. One more question: How many occurrences of each pair do you expect on average? 2? 10? 100? 10000?

Comment: @WolframH: That actually needs to be found out. It will probably depend on the fraction. When fraction = 1, that mean the whole list is considered as single window. So, lots of users will be appearing in the same ordered tuple many times. And number of lists is 90000, so some of them could easily be 1000 or may be more.

Comment: Im with senderle. I highly doubt you have an actual need to do any of this to achieve whatever your goal may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me get this straight.

You have up to about 22 billion potential tuples (for 90000 lists, any of 700, any of the following entries, on average 350) which might be less depending on the window size.  You want to find, but number of inner lists that they appear in, how many tuples there are.

Data of this size has to live on disk.  The rule for data that lives on disk due to size is, "Never randomly access, instead generate and then sort."

So I'd suggest that you write out each tuple to a log file, one tuple per line.  Sort that file.  Now all instances of any given tuple are in one place.  Then run through the file, and for each tuple emit the count of how many times it appears in (that is how many inner lists it is in).  Sort that second file.  Now run through that file, and you can extract how many tuples appeared 1x, 2x, 3x, etc.

If you have multiple machines, it is easy to convert this into a MapReduce.  (Which is morally the same approach, but you get to parallelize a lot of stuff.)

Comment: Yes, this is the only possibility it seems.But as I am running the program on my machine, the file size for fraction =0.5 has already exceeded 70GBs of disk space and the list number being inspected is 4969. I guess MapReduce is the only option then?

Comment: @NilanjanBasu Not necessarily.  Long ago (before MapReduce was published) I faced a similarly intractable problem by writing a custom merge-sort script that did both the merging and the sorting on the fly, and which would store intermediate data on disk in compressed form.  It was a lot of work, but the combination reduced the size of my intermediate data files by a couple of orders of magnitude.  (One order from compression, one from early removal of duplicate records.)  That could make your data size more tractable.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/) is one of the MapReduce implementations that is suited for this kind of problem: